# I want to Repeat Page Header on each Page for reports.Repeat on NewPage is not appearing in properties of Tablix member in SSRS 2008

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

How to Repeat Page Header on each Page.
Repeat on NewPage Property is not appearing in ssrs 2008 tablix memeber property

Answer (score 37):

After a little experimentation, I figured out how to consistently get the table header to repeat on every page.

The setting of the `RepeatColumnHeaders` property on the tablix seems to have no effect on this behavior. Instead, we have to set it on a static member of the row groups.

To see the static members of the row groups, click on the small drop down arrow on the far right of the row groups/columns groups header. Then select Advanced Mode.
[image: Advanced Mode]

With the static members of the row group shown, select the first one in the list. The top left cell of the tablix should be selected in the designer.

Now open the property pane and find the property `RepeatOnNewPage` and set it to `True`.
[image: RepeatOnNewPage]

Then find the property `KeepWithGroup` and make sure it's set to `After`. If it's not, set it to `After`.
Now your table header will repeat on every page.

Comment: Added images, so one finds "Advanced mode" more easily ;)

Comment: This just saved my life.

Comment: Better than editing XML, does seem to work every time.

Comment: This is perfect. I have 2 "header" rows that needed to repeat on every page and by following your steps my report works as intended. I love you.

Comment: I had `FixedData` and `RepeatOnNewPage` on, but as you said, they weren't repeated on page 2+ until I also added `KeepWithGroup` = `After`. Thanks!

Comment: Good answer and it's being worked for me. Thanks @Stefan Steiger

Answer (score 32):

Depending on how you created your new report, the Tablix xml may or may not have attached the correct properties to the "Header" row of the tablix.

Here is another thread on SQL Server Central with the fix:
http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic593245-1063-1.aspx

Here is the important bit:

> for SSRS 2008,
>
> If a report with a table is created using the wizard feature (In Solution Explorer, right click on >Reports --> Add New Report) Table Headers will repeat on every page.
>
> Instead if a report is created without using the wizard (In Solution Explorer, right click on Reports --> Add --> New Item) Table Headers will not repeat on every page. Setting Repeat Header (Rows/Columns) on each Page for the Tablix will not help either.
>
> If you have already built the report and cannot rebuild using the steps above and if and only if you are comfortable altering the xml behind the rdl, do the following. (Save a Backup rdl first)
>
> View Code.
>   Look for TablixRowHierarchy
>   Below that there will be a TablixMember that corresponds to the header row.
>   to that header and any other header rows ( Tablix Member) add the three element properties.

```
<TablixRowHierarchy>
  <TablixMembers>
    <TablixMember>
      <KeepWithGroup>After</KeepWithGroup>
      <RepeatOnNewPage>true</RepeatOnNewPage>
      <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
    </TablixMember>
  ...
```

> You should see the header rows repeating.

I tried this in my own Report and found it fixed the problem.

Comment: Thank you so much. This worked when nothing else would. You may find the empty TablixMembers above a TablixMember with the "Details" group in it. In my case, I had two rows to repeat and I had two empty TablixMember tags that I added the "repeat" tags to. I think this anomaly happened because of some cell merging I did.

Comment: If I could upvote this 5x, I would. Nothing but nothing I tried online worked. This is the fix.

Comment: Thanks. I wasted half a day tried combinations properties values and this one works like charmed. I wish I found this sooner

Answer (score 7):

You could also turn on "Advanced Mode" in the Row/Column Groups window and then modify each Static Row entries "RepeatOnNewPage" setting. You'll probably have to set "KeepWithGroup" to "After" as well.

This works well if you utilize a subreport as your header.

Comment: ya it worked for me but now my problem iswhile exporting to word im not getting tableheader repeated,but in pdf im getting..ny solution??

Answer (score 1):

You can repeat page headings on every page if your page breaks are due to breaks between groups (hard pagination).  You cannot repeat page headings between pages if the pagination is due to a small interactive page size (soft pagination).  To repeat page headers on each page between groups, make the headers of the tablix part of the group and under the General tab of the Tablix Properties window check Column Headers -> Repeat header rows on each page.  You can also do this from the general properties window of the Tablix by using the RepeatcolumnHeaders = True.

Please note my comments are limited to developing SSRS 2008 reports in BIDS.  I do not know if this functionality exists in Report Builder.

Comment: My report has soft pagination as you explained and none of the methods explained here to have column headers appear on each page seem to work. I suppose there is no way around it, as you said. I'd be curious to know if anyone else has figured out a way to make it work in the eight years since you left your answer.

Answer (score 1):

here the steps you can follow. this resolved the issue(column header on each page):

1) in design mode of rdl file, at bottom you will find "Row Groups" and "Column Groups" (left and right, respectively). Beside Column Groups you will find one arrow button.(this arrow button is right side of column groups protion). click on this arrow button.

2) Check the "Advanced Mode"

3) RowGroups section you will find "(static)" and "(Details)". click on static and press F4(to check it's properties.)

4) provide "Keep With Group" as "After"

5)Provide "Repeat On New Page" as "True"

6) Go back to table, Right click on row header, Go to tablix properties.

7) check on "repeat Header Column on each page" and "repeat Header column on each Rows"

Hope this will help you.

Comment: hi, can this be possible if i want to display the header on the next page from a page break?

Comment: yes. that is possible. you have to select repeat header. Please check this reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/display-row-and-column-headers-on-multiple-pages-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-2017