# SSRS show the same objects in the second page

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a Report in SSRS that displays some logos at the top of the first page. I just got a requirement to add the possibility to also show the logos in the second page -- The report is only two pages. Is there a way to repeat the same Image objects in the second page?

Comment: You want to show the header in the second page?  Else you can make the logos a function which would be displayed based on a parameter.

Comment: I don't need to repeat the header in the second page, since I have already a header independent of the lodo. How could I make the logos a function to be displayed in second function as well based on a parameter??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your report is specifically laid out to span multiple pages, you can use a repeating page header. If not (i.e., the second page is caused by content overflow), and you know it will always be two pages or less, you can use a page header and select "print on first page" and "print on last page" in report properties. Otherwise, if you have tablix controls causing the page span, and your page design allows, you can put the logos in the tablix header and enable repeat header on all pages for the tablix. If none of those work, you'll be stuck, as far as I know.

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3475144/i-want-to-repeat-page-header-on-each-page-for-reports-repeat-on-newpage-is-not-a).

Comment: The tablix header solution sounds like could work. How can I activate it??

Comment: Open the properties window on your tablix object and check "repeat header rows on each page". Then put your logos inside the tablix header. You'll probably have to play around with it to get it looking good. You might consider adding an extra, otherwise empty top level row or column group to get a header that spans the entire tablix.

Comment: Using the columns header of the Tablix object worked like a charm. I just need to figure out how to set its value dynamically from DB. It looks like it does not support setting it to an expression.

Answer (score 1):

If you are showing Image in the header then you need to following things:

Adding a Data-Bound Image to a Header or Footer
You can use image data stored in a database in a header or footer. However, you cannot reference database fields from the Image report item directly. Instead, you must add a text box in the body of the report and then set the text box to the data field that contains the image (note that the value must be base64 encoded). You can hide the text box in the body of the report to avoid showing the base64-encoded image. Then, you can reference the value of the hidden text box from the Image report item in the page header or footer.
For example, suppose you have a report that consists of product information pages. In the header of each page, you want to display a photograph of the product. To print a stored image in the report header, define a hidden text box named TXT_Photo in the body of the report that retrieves the image from the database and use an expression to give it a value:

=Convert.ToBase64String(Fields!Photo.Value)
In the header, add an Image report item which uses the TXT_Photo text box, decoded to show the image:
=Convert.FromBase64String(ReportItems!TXT_Photo.Value)

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd220421(v=sql.105).aspx

TO repeat image on every page

IN addition to this, to repeat this image into everyt page, Go to property of TXT_Photo textbox In General tab, tick the check box "Repeat report item with data region on every page" and select your region.

Thanks