# SRSS 2008 RepeatOnNewPage not really work on the "2nd last" page

Tags: sql-server

I've built a RDL with SRSS 2008 (actually it's migrated from 2005 by opening and saving in SRSS 2008)

There's a group which its visibility is controlled by input parameters. (Static) rows inside the group sets RepeatOnNewPage as True and KeepWithGroup attribute is set to "Before" as footer also.

I found that the group keeps repeating on each page just only missing in the second last page.

I have tried to set the RepeatOnNewPage be either True or False for the group but the result still be same (missing the footer in 2nd last page).

I am not sure why this happening and hope if some advise can be provided. Thanks very much.

Source can be provided as request.

Answer (score 0):

When I set `RepeatOnNewPage` to `True` I usually set `KeepWithGroup` to `After`.

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3475144/i-want-to-repeat-page-header-on-each-page-for-reports-repeat-on-newpage-is-not-a) for further details.

Comment: Thanks tezzo for comment. Isn't that KeepWithGroup = After for header before the details_group and KeepWithGroup = Before for footer after the details_group?

Comment: Sorry, I thought you have this tipycal problem with Tablix: http://vbcity.com/blogs/xtab/archive/2010/06/14/what-to-do-when-the-repeatcolumnheaders-property-in-a-tablix-isn-t-working.aspx By the way, what happens if you set KeepWithGroup = After?